# What is ComponentFixtureNoNgZone used for?

Tags: angular

There is no explanation for this variable in angular v11+ [official docs](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/ComponentFixtureNoNgZone).

And, there is even no comment for this variable from [source code]
(https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/11.0.5/packages/core/testing/src/test_bed_common.ts#L34-L33).

But it's exposed, what is `ComponentFixtureNoNgZone` used for?

Answer (score 0):

`ComponentFixtureNoNgZone` is an `InjectionToken` used by `TestBed.createComponent`.

When not set or set to `false`, the component will not be created in the Angular zone and change detection will not be automatic. Also you won't be able to call `ComponentFixture.autoDetectChanges()` which will throw.